# Followup question from an application of the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma

Tags: fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Problem statement: Let $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ be Lebesgue measurable with finite measure and $f(x) = \int_{E}\sin(tx)dt.$ Show that $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to \infty$.

Solution: We start by defining an indicator function for $E$ where $\chi_E=\begin{cases} 1 , x\in E \newline
0, x\notin E\end{cases}.$ This helps us measure the set $E$. Then I applied the assumption that $E$ has finite measure.

$\mu(E)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\chi_{E}|d\mu =||\chi_E||_{L^1}<\infty.$

Then since we have that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\chi_{E}|d\mu<\infty,$ we can apply the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma to it. Thus

$\lim_{x\to \infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\chi_E(t)e^{itx}dt = 0$ and we have that $\lim_{x\to \infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\chi_E(t)e^{itx}dt  = \lim_{x\to \infty}\int_{E}e^{itx}dt=0$.

My question is how do I conclude? I know that $\sin(tx)=\frac{e^{itx}-e^{-itx}}{2i}$. The solution I was provided says that $\lim_{x\to \infty}\int_{E}\chi_{E}(t)e^{itx}dt=\lim_{x\to \infty}\int_{E}\sin(tx)dt$, but I am not convinced that $\sin(tx)=e^{itx}$.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution does not say that $\sin(tx)=e^{itx}$. The solution is saying their integrals are equal, which you can work out using the identity you know, namely:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\int_E sin(xt)dt=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\int_\mathbb{R} \chi_E \dfrac{e^{itx}-e^{-itx}}{2i}dt=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\int_\mathbb{R} \chi_E \dfrac{e^{itx}}{2i}dt-\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\int_\mathbb{R} \chi_E \dfrac{e^{-itx}}{2i}dt=0$$

Comment: Okay, that’s reassuring that they’re not equal. I know that the first term in the different is =0 by above. And I’m thinking that the second term is also 0 because $sin(tx)$ is a real function, so the imaginary part must equal zero also. Is that it?

Comment: The Riemann-Lebesgue lemma covers both cases, the $e^{itx}$ integral going to $0$, and the $e^{-itx}$ integral going to $0$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma as you can see the lemma statement is for $|x|$, which is why it covers both cases. Moreover, $\sin$ can be defined over the complex numbers, so strictly speaking, $\sin$ is not a real function.